# Less verbose way to write a destructured typescript constructor

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to pass an object to my data model (instead of passing separate parameters). However by doing so i have to write three times as much code. Is there a less verbose way to write the object destructured code (like the parameterised way)

**First - parameterised way (for reference):**

```
export class DataModel {
    constructor(
        public suppliers: SupplierModel[],
        public inStock: boolean,
        public myFavorites: boolean,
    ) {}
}
```

**Object - destrutured way:**

```
export class DataModel {
    public suppliers: SupplierModel[];
    public inStock: boolean;
    public myFavorites: boolean;

    constructor(
        {suppliers, inStock, myFavorites}: 
        {suppliers: SupplierModel[], inStock: boolean, myFavorites: boolean 
    ) {
            this.suppliers = suppliers;
            this.inStock = inStock;
            this.myFavorites = myFavorites;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this issue: [Combining destructuring with parameter properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326)

Comment: Thanks @NitzanTomer for pointing me in the right direction. (Technically that answer is on github so not a duplicate ;) )